# C - One Loop to find Big & Small Numeric Value

Tags: c, loops

I need some help writing a program that uses one loop (no arrays) to find the biggest and smallest numeric value until the user enters -999.

We can assume at least one non-flag value and that the user will not type -999 as the first value but they can write 2 and then -999 so then the largest & smallest value would be 2.

I wrote the code to find the largest value but not sure how I can also have it find the smallest value in the same loop.

Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int big, num;
    printf("Enter a value but not -999  ");
    scanf("%d", &big);
    printf("Enter a value, -999 to quit ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while(num != -999)
    {
        if(num > big)
            big = num;
        printf("Enter a value, -999 to quit ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    printf("\nThe largest value is %d\n", big);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the first given number as big and small. Then iterate through the while loop and check the currently given number is bigger than `big` at the same time the given number is smaller than the `small`.

finally print both big and small should do the work.

```
.........

int big, num;

int small;
printf("Enter a value, -999 to quit ");
scanf("%d", &num);
big = small = num;
while(num != -999)
{
    if(num > big)
        big = num;
    if(num< small)
        small = num;
..........
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int big, num;
    printf("Enter a value but not -999  ");
    scanf("%d", &big);
    printf("Enter a value, -999 to quit ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int small=big;
    while(num != -999)
    {
        if(num > big)
        {
            big = num;
        }
        else if(num<small)
        {
         small=num;

        }

        printf("Enter a value, -999 to quit ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    printf("\nThe largest value is %d\n", big);
    printf("\nThe smallest value is %d\n", small);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just should add:

```
else if(num<smallest){
     smallest=num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `do{ } while(num != -999)` loop, to avoid duplicating the code for the prompt / scanf (instead of once before the loop, once in the loop). This would make the first iteration not special.

As everyone is answering, an extra piece of state to track (i.e. the smallest value) should be done with an extra variable

Your code is weird; it always prompts at least twice.  Normally you'd just get the first number, then set `big=small=num`.

For a `do{}while()` loop, where the first iteration is nothing special, initializing `big` and `small` is a little tricky.  If you start with (before the loop)

```
int big   = INT_MIN;   // #include <limits.h> for these
int small = INT_MAX;
do { // ....
```

then they will have the correct value after a `big=max(big, num);` because either `num` is INT_MIN, in which case they're equal and `big=INT_MIN` is correct, or `max()` (or your `if`) will pick `num` instead of the old `big`.  There are no integers smaller than `INT_MIN`, which is the whole point.  Same for `small` and `INT_MAX`.

The constants are defined in [limits.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).